# .net core 3.1 - list is being overwritten during foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a project with .NET Core 3.1 and EF with the following model defined:

```
public class CustomerModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int sales_person_id { get; set; }
        public int company_id { get; set; }
        
        [NotMapped]
        public List<FileModel> _files { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<StepModel> _steps { get; set; }
    }
```

I am fetching a list of customers from my db:

```
List<CustomerModel> customer_records = _dbContext.customers.Where(c => c.company_id == company_record.id && c.sales_person_id == agent_record.id).ToList();
```

and then trying to populate that list with the `[NotMapped]` variables as follows:

```
foreach (CustomerModel c in customer_records)
            {
                c._steps = new List<StepModel>();
                c._files = _dbContext.files.Where(f => f.company_id == company_record.id && f.customer_id == c.id).ToList();
                c._steps = await _getStepsByCustomerId(c.id);
            }
```

The `_getStepsByCustomerId` method:

```
private async Task<List<StepModel>> getStepsByCustomerId(int customer_id)
        {
            List<CustomerStepRef> _ref = await _dbContext.customer_step_ref.Where(s => s.customer_id == customer_id).ToListAsync();
            List<StepModel> steps = new List<StepModel>();
            foreach (CustomerStepRef _cs in _ref)
            {
                StepModel _step = await _dbContext.steps.FindAsync(_cs.step_id);
                _step._customer_id = _cs.customer_id;
                _step._step_status = _cs.step_status;
                steps.Add(_step);
            }
            return steps;
        }
```

Now, to the problem - the list `_steps` in `customer_records` is being overwritten during the `foreach` and eventually the `_steps` list has entries from the last iteration.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Yaniv

Comment: none related but ur code is hard to read as you have put undercore `_files ` for public propertys please change them `Files` now i will try keep that in mind when re-reading.

Comment: fix ur naming standard and things will be so much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Where can I read more on standards and conventions?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+naming+standards&rlz=1C1TIGY_enZA699ZA699&oq=c%23+naming+standards&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i65l2j69i60l2j69i65j69i60.5563j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

basically local variables should not have underscores, only private fields should.
Also public Properties should all be Pascal Case also no underscores.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious issue I see why `c._steps` will be overwritten is because instantiating the `List<StepModel>` happens within the for loop and there for will always be the populated with the last iteration. Place it on the outside and append to it. Assuming you want to append to the steps after every loop.

```
c._steps = new List<StepModel>();
foreach (CustomerModel c in customer_records)
{
    c._files = _dbContext.files.Where(f => f.company_id == company_record.id && f.customer_id == c.id).ToList();
    c._steps = await _getStepsByCustomerId(c.id);
}
```

Comment: good on u for figuring out a possible intent. for me its so unclear what is expected to happen. but if that is what he wanted the q wasnt clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

the following code solved the problem:

```
List<StepModel> _temp = await _platform.getStepsByCustomerId(c.id);
                c._steps = _temp.Select(item => new StepModel
                {
                    company_id = item.company_id,
                    step_name = item.step_name,
                    s_id = item.s_id,
                    _step_status = item._step_status,
                    _customer_id = item._customer_id
                }).ToList();
```

I think the call to the method keeps updating the same memory area, hence causing my list items to point to the same memory area which keeps on updating on each iteration.
The `_temp.Select` copies the entire list items to a new one...

Thanks